# How can I connect to the database with pypika?

Tags: python, query-builder, pypika

Reading the documentation it's pretty much clear how to build queries, but I couldn't find any tutorial how to connect to the database - i.e. instruct pypika which DB to use, which credentials etc. How can I connect to the database with pypika?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't connect to a database with pypika. Pypika is only a tool that makes SQL query strings. It doesn't have the functionality you are looking for.

You make the query string with the help of pypika, and you throw that string to your database system with packages that can do that, like pymysql for MySQL or psycopg for PostgreSQL.